# Intellij places the web folder in wrong directory?

Tags: jsf, maven, intellij-idea

According to sources I have found, the webapp folder for a JSF project should be in the folder where the folder 'java' is. One of these sources is [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/primefaces-hello-world-example/).

When I create a maven project with IntelliJ 12 and add JSF Framework support, intellij creates a folder named "web" where the folder "src" is. So even when everything is fine, when I type mvn verify in the folder, maven complains that it can not find the file web.xml. When I move the folder "web" to where it should be and rename it to "webapp", everything works fine.

But why is this so in IntelliJ?

Comment: Do you import the project from the `pom.xml`? IDEA should use the [standard Maven layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) when importing.

Comment: I go to File - New Project. Then choose maven module. I do not choose any archetype. Then, I right click on the project and choose Add Framework support - JSF.

Comment: @CrazyCoder When I do not choose maven, but a Java Module and JSF, still the directory layout is different than the standart JSF.

Comment: Import the pom, standard new project wizard doesn't follow Maven layout.

Comment: @CrazyCoder But I do not have a pom initially? I want to start a maven project in IntelliJ then add JSF support. How can I do this?

Comment: Create pom from some archetype, manually or download a sample pom somewhere.

Comment: Are there any archetypes you can suggest? Which one should I use?